# After i have installed sp1 on vs2010 Ultimate the asp:controls stopped showing in intellisence

Tags: intellisense, servercontrols, visual-studio-2010

I have tried to reinstall it but it didn't worked, now i don't have any intellisence on the server controls only html and css in .aspx files.

Does some one know how fix it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear reflected schemas folder(of course backup it first :) ) and restart studio

On my Win Xp it on

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<UserName>\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas
```

Comment: Where can i find it in WINDOWS 7?

Comment: @IamStalker, I dont really sure, think somewhere here -  C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas